# Page Rotation Without Rotating Device

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, orientation, device-orientation

I want to know that can we Rotate App Pages(Views) in Windows Phone without actually rotating the device. What my need is I want to rotate a Page upside down in `Portrait Orientation`.
Also, Windows Phone only support 3 sided orientation, so that I left with only one option i.e. to rotate the Page.
Another thing I can do in this respect is to take the `Grid` and rotate it using `StoryBoard` Please suggest or share your valuable knowledge whether I can achieve this task without moving Device.

Thank you.

Comment: you have to use storeyboard because your problem come in the zone of transion so soteryboard is a good option

Comment: Ok fine but is there no other way to rotate whole page without rotating the device as its persist when orientation change.

Comment: actually when you check xaml page what you will find is VSM(visual state manager) so what happen is when you rotate your device basically your app visual state changes on the basis of that corresponding by default storeboard started so if can find this basic storeyboard under the trasition collection of page you can use it directly. i am sure that it will available somewhere so do some search.hope this helps you.

Comment: I know how to do that using StoryBoard :), Thanks @tanuj_loop

Comment: i was sure of it but what i wanted to say is - that type of effect is inbuilt so if you can trace that out it will helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties of the PhoneApplicationPage in xaml, such as select the orientation of the page, there is an option for PortraitDown? That may be what you are looking for. (If you want to change the orientation in C# just give the PhoneApplicationPage a name then just use the orientation property.